# CSS Image Swap One at a Time

Tags: css, image, swap

JSFiddle Here: https://jsfiddle.net/br84z1Lj/

On hover, both images swap, instead of just one.  If I end the div for "swapMe" and restart it for the next image, it puts the next image on the next line, instead of staying in line.  I'm completely stuck on getting only one image to change on hover instead of both!

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

#thumbs {
  width: 460px;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: justify;
  -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}

#thumbs a {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}

.stretch {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0
}

.swapMe img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.swap1,
.swapMe:hover .swap2 {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.swapMe:hover .swap1,
.swap2 {
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

  <div id="thumbs">
    <div class="swapMe">

      <a id="single_image1" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200/000000/fff" class="swap1" style="position: absolute" height="150" width="188" alt="" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200/d100d1/fff" height="150" width="188" class="swap2">
      </a>

      <a id="single_image2" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200/000000/fff" class="swap1" style="position: absolute" height="150" width="188" alt="" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200/d100d1/fff" height="150" width="188" class="swap2">
      </a>



      <span class="stretch"></span>

    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is this what you would like to accomplish? https://jsfiddle.net/br84z1Lj/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revising  your bottom hover statement to this should do the trick, if I'm understanding what you're looking for! Side note, prefixed opacity declarations aren't really necessary at this point, every modern browser within any version I can think of supports plain old opacity.

```
.swap1:hover,
.swap2:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/will0220/awpv02p7/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I just used a tutorial for this code - what are the prefixed opacity declarations you're talking about?

Also, I was able to fix my code using spans instead of divs, but this seems to work too!

Comment: Sure! I just mean -webkit-opacity, -moz-opacity etc - just opacity works in every modern browser at this point.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap the 2 images in separate `div`'s.  You can use `display: inline-block`

I updated your fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/br84z1Lj/1/

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

#thumbs {
  width: 460px;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: justify;
  -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}

#thumbs a {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}

.stretch {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0
}
.swapMe {
  display: inline-block;
}    
.swapMe img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.swap1,
.swapMe:hover .swap2 {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.swapMe:hover .swap1,
.swap2 {
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

  <div id="thumbs">
    <div class="swapMe">

      <a id="single_image1" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200/000000/fff" class="swap1" style="position: absolute" height="150" width="188" alt="" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200/d100d1/fff" height="150" width="188" class="swap2">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="swapMe">
      <a id="single_image2" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200/000000/fff" class="swap1" style="position: absolute" height="150" width="188" alt="" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200/d100d1/fff" height="150" width="188" class="swap2">
      </a>
    </div>


    <span class="stretch"></span>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do try this css code:

```
.swap1,
.swapMe a:hover .swap2 {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.swapMe a:hover .swap1,
.swap2 {
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```